# Windows Font Size screws up WPF application

Tags: wpf, datacontext, font-size

We're having this weird bug where if the application is opened and the user changes the windows font size here:

[image]

When the font size is changed to extra large, one of our controls `DataContext` is changed to null, and its `DataContextChanged` event is called too.

Not really sure what is going on, nor why or what changes the `DataContext` of the control. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be a hand-drawn circle, not a fancy arrow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming *ChartItemControl* is a *System.Windows.Controls.Control* or *UserControl*.  A *Control's* *Unloaded* event will be fired when modifying the windows theme, color scheme, or font size.  If you are cleaning up resources by resetting *DataContext* when handling the *Unloaded* event, you will need to reset your *DataContext* when the control is loaded again or in *OnApplyTemplate*.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I had no idea this happened. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, do you know what other events happen when the font is changed? I need an event that happens BEFORE Unloaded (OnApplyTemplate works), and one that happens AFTER, so I can set true to a flag in OnApplyTemplate, and set it to false in the event that happens after. Thanks!

Comment: Or if is there a way for the control to completely ignore the Windows change?

Comment: I do not know of any events that would happen "after" a control is Unloaded.  I am unsure what you wish to accomplish with the flag.  

It is impractical to ignore the change, since the default templates for primative WPF controls adapt to the selected theme.  This design allows WPF applications to maintain a consistant appearance with Win32/WinForms applications, even though Win32 messages are not used to draw the UI components.

I recommend designing your controls such that the same instance may be unloaded and reloaded without losing state.